# How do I pass a 2-dimensional array in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I just can't figure out how to pass my 2 dimensional array in Objective-C. I would love some help on what I'm doing wrong. I keep on getting an error saying:

> conflicting types for 'displayGameBoard'

Here is my code:

```
//protype  
void displayGameBoard (NSInteger)

//int main function
 NSInteger gameBoard [3][3] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // declaring 
 // caller     
  displayGameBoard (gameBoard [3][3])


// function receiving data from array
void displayGameBoard (NSInteger gameBoard [3][3])
{
   // rest of my code 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's exactly the same as 2-dimension array in C language.

Your function definition is fine but the declaration is incorrect. It should be

```
void displayGameBoard (NSInteger[3][3]);
```

as it's in the definition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you are calling your function. Writing

```
displayGameBoard (gameBoard [3][3])
```

`gameBoard [3][3]` means the element at the 4th row of the 4th column. When you do that get an `NSInterger`. However `displayGameBoard` expects a pointer to an `NSInteger` or `NSInteger *`. So the compiler is seeing a type mismatch and causing your error.

The way to correct this is

```
//protype  
void displayGameBoard (NSInteger[3][3]) // Must have the same argument type in your pro to type as the implementation.

//int main function
NSInteger gameBoard [3][3] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // declaring 
// caller     
displayGameBoard (gameBoard) // Place in the entire array not just an element


// function receiving data from array
void displayGameBoard (NSInteger gameBoard [3][3])
{
    // rest of my code 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a 2-dimensional array, it should be initialized as such:

```
NSInteger gameBoard [3][3] = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
```